# node-sqlite3 memory usage increasing with time

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm a new user for node.js,
now I have a problem for using node-sqlite3
I write a testing code as below.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('jobTracker.sqlite');
setInterval(function(){
db.serialize(function(){
    db.run('INSERT INTO code_list (code_path) VALUES(?)', "test", function(err){
        if(err){
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
});
}, 10);
```

node-sqlite3 memory usage increasing with time.
After 1Day, It's using 200MB memory.
Is there Something wrong with my code?

node-sqlite version: "sqlite3": "~2.1.19"
node.js version: v0.10.21

Comment: Virtual memory usage or physical memory usage?

Comment: physical memory usage. :)